# Angular parse error - Token is an unexpected token

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a basic `directive` that updates the time within a div:

```
myApp.directive('updateTime', function($timeout, $filter) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var timeoutId;

        function updateTime() {
            element.text($filter('dateFromNow')(attrs.updateTime));$()
        }

        scope.$watch(attrs.updateTime, function(value) {
            updateTime();
        });

        function updateLater() {
            timeoutId = $timeout(function() {
                updateTime();
                updateLater();
            }, 5000);
        }

        element.bind('$destroy', function() {
            $timeout.cancel(timeoutId);
        });

        updateLater();
    }
});
```

My model contains a date object, like so `2016-06-03T09:14:57.948Z`, yet Angular seems to be complaining about it being in that format. It is how my database (MongoDB) delivers the date.

```
Error: $parse:syntax
Syntax Error
Syntax Error: Token 'T09' is an unexpected token at column 11 of the expression [2016-06-03T09:14:57.948Z] starting at [T09:14:57.948Z].
```

How can I get around this error?

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/zilions/pen/KMpgpJ)**

**EDIT:**

This is my `dateFromNow` filter. It simply just converts a date object (or date string) to a `time ago` string (such as "2 minutes ago") with MomentJS:

```
myApp.filter('dateFromNow', function () {
    return function (date, onlyFromNow) {
        return moment(date).fromNow();
    }
});
```

In my console, I can see that the error occurs within my `scope.$watch(....` within my directive.

Comment: Ad "Working Example": The date filter converts a date to a string, not the other way around. As for your question, we don't know what the "dateFromNow" filter does and what input it expects.

Comment: @zeroflagL - Thanks for letting me know. I have made an edit to my question to add the filter. It's very basic, just uses MomentJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error gets thrown from `scope.$watch` because you are passing the actual value (2016-06-03T09:14:57.948Z) while it needs to know a name (or path) of the variable.

You can fix it with a few modifications.

Use your directive like below:

```
<div update-time="myTime">
```

Get the attribute value in `updateTime()` by parsing it:

```
 $parse(attrs.updateTime)(scope)
```

This requires the `$parse` service to be injected to your directive:

```
.directive('updateTime', function($timeout, $filter, $parse) {
    // ...
})
```

Here is a working example:
http://codepen.io/LukaszWiktor/pen/BzNLOM

Comment: Your working example uses the date filter, not the filter from the question.

Comment: Right! I just forked the example from a link "Working Example" provided in the question.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Lukasz. Will have to keep that in mind.